# How to use ranges in formulas with external sheet links

Tags: google-sheets, sum, vlookup, sumifs, google-query-language

I'd like to use a `SUMIF` formula in one sheet that references a range in a separate sheet.

My problem is that using the range in this situation is only working for the first column of the range. So if my formula is:

```
=SUMIF('Data Referenced'!$A$2:$A,Formula!$A2,'Data Referenced'!$B$2:$M$11)
```

then it only adds as if I used the range `B2:B`. Using the same formula with internal ranges works fine as expected, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've laid out my example in the Google Doc linked below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zT2GlElgW5JkU90sOBeVlhr7FDOYeqaysDE-39fyao/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({'Data Referenced'!A2:A11, 
 MMULT('Data Referenced'!B2:M11*1, 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS('Data Referenced'!B2:M11))^0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your formula is doing, but the total for "Jimmy" should be "4", "Greg" should be "9", and "Amy" should be "11".

Comment: It works perfectly! I'd appreciate if you explained your solution a bit, but seeing as this may be a niche situation, it may not be a huge deal for most people. Thanks!

Comment: @Chopin23 sure. we use MMULT to sum all values per each row. there are empty cells in range B2:M11 so we multiply all cells by 1 to convert empty cells to 0 because MMULT works only with numeric values. then we construct virtual array with {} to have 2 columns (names and sum of each row. next we perform sum with QUERY where we group by names. theis well output us all names and all totals so we can use it in VLOOKUP to look up specific names in column A and return 2nd column of QUERY with totals if names in column A matches names of first column of QUERY. IFNA is to remove possible errors.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks again for the help!